# Selenium WebDriver + Firefox causes error: cross-process JS call failed

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium

When I try to run this simple test on the latest version Firefox I get an error.

Test:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: cross-process JS call failed
```

This test works correctly in Chrome.

Interesting, that this error happens after second executing of the test after PC restarting. Clearing of cache and killing processes in task manager did not help.